# What algorithm can I use to verify that a list of nodes can be connected, given some constraints?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm building a game where the player is given a random set of nodes and attempts to build the longest list they can by placing the nodes in a certain order.  Each node has zero or more connections on the sides that have to match with at least one connection on the side of the next node in the list. For example, a node might look like this:

```
                  +--+
left connections  A  B right connections
                  B  C
                  +--+
```

The above node (example node) could be connected with any of these nodes:

```
+--+
C  |  This node can connect to the right side of the example node (matches C)
D  |
+--+

+--+
B  K  This node can connect to the left side of the example node (matches A)
L  A  This node can connect to the right side of the example node (matches B)
+--+
```

So, given those three nodes, the player could match them up in a list like so:

```
+--+     +--+     +--+
B  K     A  B     C  |
L  A -A- B  C -C- D  |
+--+     +--+     +--+
```

I need to validate that the player's choices.  The player doesn't have to select the nodes in the correct order at first, but their resulting final selections must be able to connect into a contiguous, linear list.

So, given an array of unordered nodes (the players selection), I need to form the nodes into a valid list like above, or show an error to the player.

I can brute force the validation, but I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: How big will these sets be?  If not very, something more elaborate than brute force might not be worth the trouble.  For big sets, dynamic programming might be appropriate.

Comment: @ScottHunter The player's selections could be 5 or 6 nodes long.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to trace a path from left to right with no cycles?  i.e. you could only move in one direction (right) on a link `-A-` and you can only move up/down/right.  

If you're worried about the user building multiple paths that would dead end, you're then really looking for a depth first traversal of a tree where at least one leaf reaches the destination "side".  If you want shortest path, I'm thinking dykstra's algorithm may work here (but I'm a bit fuzzy on it).

Answer (score 1):

After hash up and some precalculations the problem may look like this:

```
Given a graph determine whether it has a path traversing all nodes
```

which is exactly [the Hamiltonian problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). You may read researches on this topic or analyze certain structure of your graph (for some special graphs it has simple solutions), but in general case the best solution I know is exponential.

However the straightforward brute force solution is to go through all permutations (`n!`) and check whether it forms proper path (`*n`). This approach results in `O(n*n!)` asymptotic. Effectively it means that `n` should be about `12` at maximum for sub-second check and for `n=15` it will take several hours to check in the worst case.

Slight optimisation - forming the path gradually and checking on every new vertex - results in `O(n!)` time in the worst case, so it will be possible to check for `n=13` in a couple of seconds in the worst case and even faster in average as a lot of false paths will be cut at early stages.

You may go further and take advantage of dynamic programming. Let us define `isProperPath[S][i]` (where `S` is a bitmask of subset of nodes, `i` is some node of this subset) as value corresponding to existence of path constructed of nodes of subset corresponding to `S` with the last node `i`. Then it is easy to compute `isProperPath[S][i]` based on all values for subsets with less elements then in `S`:

```
isProperPath[S][i] = false;
for (j in S) {
    if (isProperPath[S\i][j] && hasConnection(j, i))
        isProperPath[S][i] = true;
}
```

By traversing all pairs of `S` and `i` in order of ascending size of `S` we will compute all values. And the answer is true if and only if `isProperPath[A][i] = true` where `A` is the whole given set and `i` - any of nodes.

Time complexity is `O(2^n*n^2)`, space complexity is `O(2^n*n)` as there are `2^n*n` values and it takes `O(n)` to compute value based on previous values. This algorithm makes it possible to check sets of size up to `24` in a sub-second time utilizing about `400M` bits or `50Mb`.